# Unable to read dates with F# TypeProvider

Tags: sql-server, f#, type-providers

I'm trying to get a F# console application that queries a MS SQL SERVER running in Docker. I'm using the [SQLProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) to run a select statement against the DB, in the beginning only pulling an int ID. It works fine in Windows, but not in a Docker container. It fails with the error message:

```
 System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: No mapping exists from SqlDbType Date to a known DbType.
```

Parameter name: SqlDbType

I've tried both the mono:4.2.3.4 and teh fsharp/fsharp Docker images. I'm also pulling the FSharp.Core library with me.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Edit:
The Docker container runs on Linux, with mono version 4.22.2.

This is my query:

```
type private connection = SqlDataProvider<ConnectionString="CONNECTIONSTRING",
                                      DatabaseVendor=Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
                                      UseOptionTypes=true>

let private ctx = connection.GetDataContext()

let private application = "E-Mail an PH - eFeedback"

let history =
    query {
        for eh in ctx.Dbo.ActionHistoryEmail do
        join gah in ctx.Dbo.GenericActionHistory on (eh.Id = gah.Id)
        where (eh.Application = application)
        select gah.Id
    }
    |> Seq.toList
```

The stacktrace:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$Company-EFeedbackExport>.$Repository' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: No mapping exists from SqlDbType Date     to a known DbType.
Parameter name: SqlDbType
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.SetSqlDbType (SqlDbType type) <0x411a3080 + 0x00afb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.set_SqlDbType (SqlDbType value) <0x411a3040 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0

  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter:set_SqlDbType (System.Data.SqlDbType)
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Providers.MSSqlServer.getDbType@27 (Int32 providerType) <0x411a17c0 + 0x0008b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Providers.MSSqlServer+mappings@38.GenerateNext (IEnumerable`1& next) <0x411999f0 + 0x007bb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1[T].MoveNextImpl () <0x41199790 + 0x00069> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1[T].System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext () <0x41199760 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T] (IEnumerable`1 source) <0x411991c0 + 0x001ea> in <filename unknown>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Providers.MSSqlServer.createTypeMappings (IDbConnection con) <0x411761d0 + 0x00097> in <filename unknown>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Providers.MSSqlServerProvider.FSharp-Data-Sql-Common-ISqlProvider-CreateTypeMappings (IDbConnection con) <0x411761a0 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0
  at <StartupCode$FSharp-Data-SqlProvider>.$SqlRuntime.DataContext.f@1-29 (System.String runtimeAssembly, System.String resolutionPath, System.String[] referencedAssemblies, DatabaseProviderTypes providerType,     System.String owner, FSharp.Data.Sql.Runtime.SqlDataContext this, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar0) <0x401883d0 + 0x00109> in <filename unknown>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Runtime.SqlDataContext..ctor (System.String typeName, System.String connectionString, DatabaseProviderTypes providerType, System.String resolutionPath, System.String[] referencedAssemblies,     System.String runtimeAssembly, System.String owner, CaseSensitivityChange caseSensitivity) <0x401880b0 + 0x00153> in <filename unknown>:0
  at <StartupCode$Company-EFeedbackExport>.$Repository..cctor () <0x40187650 + 0x002ab> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Program.main (System.String[] args) <0x4016de00 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for '<StartupCode$Company-EFeedbackExport>.$Repository' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: No     mapping exists from SqlDbType Date to a known DbType.
Parameter name: SqlDbType
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.SetSqlDbType (SqlDbType type) <0x411a3080 + 0x00afb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter.set_SqlDbType (SqlDbType value) <0x411a3040 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0

  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter:set_SqlDbType (System.Data.SqlDbType)
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Providers.MSSqlServer.getDbType@27 (Int32 providerType) <0x411a17c0 + 0x0008b> in <filename unknown>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Providers.MSSqlServer+mappings@38.GenerateNext (IEnumerable`1& next) <0x411999f0 + 0x007bb> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1[T].MoveNextImpl () <0x41199790 + 0x00069> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.GeneratedSequenceBase`1[T].System-Collections-IEnumerator-MoveNext () <0x41199760 + 0x00017> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.ToList[T] (IEnumerable`1 source) <0x411991c0 + 0x001ea> in <filename unknown>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Providers.MSSqlServer.createTypeMappings (IDbConnection con) <0x411761d0 + 0x00097> in <filename unknown>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Providers.MSSqlServerProvider.FSharp-Data-Sql-Common-ISqlProvider-CreateTypeMappings (IDbConnection con) <0x411761a0 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0
  at <StartupCode$FSharp-Data-SqlProvider>.$SqlRuntime.DataContext.f@1-29 (System.String runtimeAssembly, System.String resolutionPath, System.String[] referencedAssemblies, DatabaseProviderTypes providerType,     System.String owner, FSharp.Data.Sql.Runtime.SqlDataContext this, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar0) <0x401883d0 + 0x00109> in <filename unknown>:0
  at FSharp.Data.Sql.Runtime.SqlDataContext..ctor (System.String typeName, System.String connectionString, DatabaseProviderTypes providerType, System.String resolutionPath, System.String[] referencedAssemblies,     System.String runtimeAssembly, System.String owner, CaseSensitivityChange caseSensitivity) <0x401880b0 + 0x00153> in <filename unknown>:0
  at <StartupCode$Company-EFeedbackExport>.$Repository..cctor () <0x40187650 + 0x002ab> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Program.main (System.String[] args) <0x4016de00 + 0x00087> in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Docker has nothing to do with this. If your Docker image runs on Windows, you still run Windows. If it runs on Linux, you are using either Mono or DotNet core. Please post your code, the full exception message including the call stack (call Exception.ToString()) and specify what kind of .NET you run on.

Comment: Please post the the full exception, including the call stack. If this is a bug in Mono, the call stack will show which method raised the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET doesn't have a Date type yet. In standard .NET `Date` is mapped to DateTime. Mono's [SqlParameter](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlParameter.cs) performs this mapping in three places. Two of them map `Date` and `DateTime` to the same type. The [third](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlParameter.cs#L741) though doesn't map `date`. I suspect that the call stack shows the exception is thrown inside `SetSqlDbType`.

<strike>Please post the exception's call stack in the question</strike>

It seems a similar [Mono bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24719) about DateTime2 was filed in 2014. This was fixed but `Date` is still missing

Comment: It's `SetSqlDbType` indeed. A [similar bug ](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=24719) was fixed for DateTime2 but not Date

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks